# Blender Grabbing Vertices Duplicates Them

Tags: vertex-groups

I'm following a tutorial on how to make a low poly character and whenever the guy im watching grabs certain vertices and pulls them they move but for me, the create a duplicate version of its already existing vertices and i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

you must have duplicated your mesh, you can try 2 different things:

- Select and delete the duplication: put your mouse on the mesh and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select the duplication, then <kbd>G</kbd> to move it away and <kbd>X</kbd> to delete.
- Merge the overlapping vertices: Select the whole mesh with <kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*, you can see how many vertices have been deleted on the top horizontal bar, meaning there were overlapping vertices, maybe you'll have to play with the *Merge Distance* parameter in the operator box on the bottom left of the 3D viewport window.