# Blender "duplicates" parts of objects when grabbing

Tags: vertex-groups

I duplicated an object, added a loop cut and tried grabbing the loop cut in order to make the object look less straight.
As you can see in the following video, that didn't work out:

[image: Video of me trying to grab the loop cut]

I researched for a long time now and the most reasonable reason would be me having accidentally duplicated the mesh too, for which I found a solution:

[Blender Grabbing Vertices Duplicates Them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157005/blender-grabbing-vertices-duplicates-them)

... but that didn't work.

Either it's not letting me select anything with "L" or, when I manage to select something, I can't delete it with "Del".

I am obviously missing something and I don't think it's a bug in Blender.

Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like you've duplicated your mesh, please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Did you make this with Bridge Edge Loops?

Comment: You can't delete with Del? And what about using X? And is there any message in the status bar saying why it won't delete anything?

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded the file. 
If you try to replicate what I did above, you should get the same results.
Edit: Someone already helped out. Have fun with my donut^^.

Comment: you need to share the URL it gives, but anyway it looks your problem is solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point when the whole mesh been selected you accidently pressed <kbd>E</kbd> (Extrude). Even if you pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> or Right Mouse Button its duplicated the mesh.

Or duplicated it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and tried to cancel the action the same way above.

If you are in Vertex Select mode the <kbd>L</kbd> button only works if you hover your mouse reasonably close to a vertex, same with the Edge Select.

Can't delete it with <kbd>Del</kbd>? Maybe you Extruded/Duplicated multiple times, and when you are able to select something and delete it, you don't see any change because there are multiple layers of the same mesh.

In Edit mode: Press <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd>, Merge by Distance.

Comment: Merging by distance helped.
Thanks for the quick answer, quite a dumb rookie mistake I suppose.

Is there any way of knowing something like that happened to eliminate errors in advance?
Like me accidentally pressing <kbd>E</kbd>or something.

Comment: If you changed your mind, or made a wrong selection and duplicated it with E or Shift + D, always press Ctrl + Z. Or turn on Auto Merge Vertices (Edit mode)